# Whats wrong with my jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

This is some basic jquery but its not working. I have a description for each video in my database. Quite simple when you hover over the info button the description for each video should fade in. ITS NOT WORKING??? WHY?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.infoBtn').mouseenter(function(){
          $('.relatedVideoDescription', this).fadeIn();
      });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="relatedvideo" style=" line-height: 138%;">
                    <div style="float: left; width: 38%;">
                        <img src="'.URL.'images/uploads/'.$img_url2.'" width="190px" />
                    </div><div class="relatedText">
                        <strong style="font-size: 12px;">'.$title2.'</strong><br />
                        <p class="relatedVideoDescription">'.$desc2.'</p>
                        <p class="infoBtn">info</p>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                <hr />
                </div>
```

The .relatedVideoDescription is set to display:none; in the CSS.

Comment: can you please also show your html? jut a guess $(this).children('.relatedVideoDescription').fadeIn();

Comment: Assuming the `relatedVideoDescription` is part of the `infoBtn`, have you tried `$(this).find('.relatedVideoDescription').fadeIn();`?

Comment: Of course element is hidden before calling fadeIn() on it

Comment: you are using context selector here which is wrong: `$('.relatedVideoDescription', this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7prVd/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.infoBtn').mouseenter(function(){
           $(this).closest('.relatedvideo').find('.relatedVideoDescription').fadeIn();
      });
});
```

**UPDATE**

or use .siblings() as Anton says

http://jsfiddle.net/7prVd/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.infoBtn').mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).siblings('.relatedVideoDescription').fadeIn();
      });
  });
```

Comment: This works great. What was I doing so wrong?

Comment: @AndrewJohn You were selecting a descedant that's why it didn't work. The element you were looking for is right next to infoBtn

Comment: @AndrewJohn you used this in a way I never did :-) in the above mouseenter function $(this) is is $('.infoBtn'). Many times if I just try and error i'll strart a function and then inside the function I write $(this).addClass('xx'); just to see where I am at.